# Spam emails strange wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, email, spam

I'm receiving strange emails can't stop them even using re-captcha in my site where it says they're comming from. 
[image]

Comment: What's the question? This doesn't seem to be about programming...

Comment: I know it doesn't have to do with programming but thought someone had same problem and could help me.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to you is that you should redirect your question to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

You're not giving us any information for your WordPress configuration to help determine what might be happening. I am guessing, but this looks like your form has been exploited. My suggestion would be to disable your forms to see if that stops the traffic. I also suggest you look at your WordPress configurations and disable comments or any other way someone can contact you, since that could be the other issue.

Good luck.